# Using scanf to read a file in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I'm in my first-ever class about C, and I'm having some trouble with a program we're writing. Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <stdlib.h>

//Prototypes
void readScores(int* scores, int* actualCount);
void displayScores(int* scores, int* actualCount);

int main() {
int arrayCount = 100;
int scores[arrayCount];
int actualCount = 0;

readScores(scores, &actualCount);
displayScores(scores, &actualCount);
}

void readScores(int* scores, int* actualCount) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    *actualCount = *actualCount + 1;
    scanf("%d", scores);
    }
} 

void displayScores(int* scores, int* actualCount) {
    for(int i = 1; i < *actualCount; i++) {
        printf("score %d: \t%d\n", i, *scores);
    }
}
```

My goal is to simply read scores from the scores.txt text file and add them to the scores[] array. Our goal in this assignment is to learn more about pointers, so don't bother trying to make my code more "efficient" or anything.

My problem is that when I compile the code with

```
gcc histogram.c -std=c99 -o histogram
```

and run it with

```
./histogram <scores.txt
```

my output looks like this:

```
score 1: 7
score 2: 7
score 3: 7
score 4: 7
score 5: 7
score 6: 7
score 7: 7
score 8: 7
score 9: 7
score 10: 7
```

How can I modify my code so that it reads the text file correctly? This problem has been bothering me all week and a solution would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format `"%d"` reads only a *single* value.

Comment: In your code where are you trying to read scores from .txt file?

Comment: "Using scanf to read a file in C" - don't. Use `fgets()`.

Comment: @Deepika Sethi  OP's "./histogram <scores.txt" implies the text is read from `stdin` via re-directed input.

Comment: @chux Thanks for clarifying. Don't know about linux much. Still learning.

Comment: @Deepika Sethi Note: using `<`, `|`, `>`  [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)#Redirecting_standard_input_and_standard_output) is common on many operating systems including windows, Unix variants, etc.

Comment: @chux: yes I know the use of these characters. But when we usually code in windows, we declare a file pointer and use fgets to read a file. When I saw this program I didn't see that and didn't notice that he has passed filename during runtime. That's why I asked a general question just to clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since scores is an array, you can use more than the first element:

```
void readScores(int* scores, int* actualCount) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    *actualCount = *actualCount + 1;
    scanf("%d", scores + i);  // Read into element i of array scores
    }
} 

void displayScores(int* scores, int* actualCount) {
    for(int i = 1; i < *actualCount; i++) {
        printf("score %d: \t%d\n", i, *(scores + i));  // Print element i of array scores
    }
}
```

Comment: For this lab we're only supposed to use brackets[] in main, otherwise I'd do that for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the value of pointer:

```
void readScores(int* scores, int* actualCount) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    *actualCount = *actualCount + 1;
    scanf("%d", scores++);
    }
}
```

of course when displaying too:

```
void displayScores(int* scores, int* actualCount) {
    for(int i = 1; i < *actualCount; i++) {
        printf("score %d: \t%d\n", i, *scores++);
    }
```